# Kibana-7.2.0-windows-x86_64 is not starting. Getting Fatal error. Cannot find module './plugins/xpack_main

Tags: kibana, kibana-7

I am new to Kibana and trying to run the Kibana server on my Windows machine.
At the time of running the Kibana.bat, I am getting fatal error that plugins/xpack_main cannot be find.

- Kibana Version = Kibana-7.2.0-windows-x86_64
- Windows = 64 Bit
- Java8= 64 Bit

I tried to manually install the xpack_main plugin after downloading the xpack_main plugin file from net.Kibana is not allowing me to install the plugin and showing the message that xpack_main plugin comes by default in the Kibana latest versions"

***Error Log:***

```
C:\softwares\estack\kibana-7.2.0-windows-x86_64\bin>kibana.bat
  log   [10:01:22.101] [fatal][root] { Error: Cannot find module './plugins/xpack_main'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\softwares\estack\kibana-7.2.0-windows-x86_64\x-pack/index.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Module._compile (C:\softwares\estack\kibana-7.2.0-windows-x86_64\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\softwares\estack\kibana-7.2.0-windows-x86_64\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at createPack (C:\softwares\estack\kibana-7.2.0-windows-x86_64\src\legacy\plugin_discovery\plugin_pack\create_pack.js:33:18)
    at MapSubscriber.packageJson$.pipe [as project] (C:\softwares\estack\kibana-7.2.0-windows-x86_64\src\legacy\plugin_discovery\plugin_pack\create_pack.js:66:11)
    at MapSubscriber._next (C:\softwares\estack\kibana-7.2.0-windows-x86_64\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:46:35)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\softwares\estack\kibana-7.2.0-windows-x86_64\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber._next (C:\softwares\estack\kibana-7.2.0-windows-x86_64\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:87:26)
    at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\softwares\estack\kibana-7.2.0-windows-x86_64\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at Subject.next (C:\softwares\estack\kibana-7.2.0-windows-x86_64\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subject.js:57:25)
    at ConnectableSubscriber.Subscriber._next (C:\softwares\estack\kibana-7.2.0-windows-x86_64\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:87:26) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

 FATAL  Error: Cannot find module './plugins/xpack_main'
```

Comment: I downgraded my Kibana and elastic search version to ver 6.0 and now it is launching.

Comment: Xpack is now part of kibana / Elastic distribution in latest versions. You can enable them in the properties file if you want to use them.